# Escaping CSS in Media Query

Tags: html, css, escaping, media-queries

I have a class that is just numbers, so I've used the [escaping methods specified by w3](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-syntax-3/#escaping) which is working as desired.

However, if I wrap it in a media query, like below, it doesn't work...

```
@media (min-width: 1000px) {
    .\33 47 {
        left: -115px;
    } 
}
```

Is there a way to use CSS escaping within a media query?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It works just fine. What special character are you trying to escape?

```css
.\26 B {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: red;
}

@media (min-width: 500px) {
  .\26 B {
    background-color: blue;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="&B"></div>
```

Number class:

```css
.\31 3 {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: #bada55;
}

@media (min-width: 500px) {
  .\31 3 {
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    background-color: purple;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="13"></div>
```

**Note**: check the snippet in full screen

Comment: Thanks buddy, I think there must have been a caching issue with my CMS! After leaving it overnight it seems to be working now.

Comment: always check the rendered code on the browser. You can disable cache on devTools